# Jquery when ; value not set

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, .when

I need to repalce the href of a 'title' class elements  in the page on the basis of the 0 or x value returned from [http://kasaragodyellowpages.com/pagedata.php?id=x](http://kasaragodyellowpages.com/pagedata.php?id=6). this url is set to 1 for testing. work currectly to ajax requests.

**problem is late response and  failure in when**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.title').each(function() {
        var url = null;
            var l = this.href;
        id_str= (l.replace('http://www.kasaragodyellowpages.com/index.php?page=item&id=',''));
        var loadUrl = "pagedata.php";  
        $.get(  
            loadUrl,  
            {id: id_str},  
            function(responseText){  
               if (responseText!=0) {
                url='http://www.kasaragodyellowpages.com/index.php?page=page&id='+responseText;
                console.log('data value for '+url);
               }
            }  
        );
        if(url){
          console.log('set data for '+url);
          $(this).attr( 'href', url );
        }else
        {
          console.log('NOT set data for '+url);
        }
        });


     });
     </script>
```

As in the image the ajax result is set after the setting the value from loop with out waiting for ajax success

[image]
After this i replaced with when

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.title').each(function() {
        var url = null;
            var l = this.href;
        id_str= (l.replace('http://www.kasaragodyellowpages.com/index.php?page=item&id=',''));
        var loadUrl = "pagedata.php";
        $.when($.get(
            loadUrl,  
            {id: id_str},  
            function(responseText){  
               if (responseText!=0) {
                url='http://www.kasaragodyellowpages.com/index.php?page=page&id='+responseText;
                console.log('data value for '+url);
               }
            }  
        ))
    .then(if(url){
          console.log('set data for '+url);
          $(this).attr( 'href', url );
        }else
        {
          console.log('NOT set data for '+url);
        }); 

        });
     });
     </script>
```

But this didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your first code, replace your call to $.get with

```
     $('.title').each(function() {
      var url = null;
      var self = this;
        .
        .
        .
        .

 $.get(  
        loadUrl,  
        {id: id_str},  
        function(responseText){  
           if (responseText!=0) {
            url='http://www.kasaragodyellowpages.com/index.php?page=page&id='+responseText;
            console.log('data value for '+url);


  if(url){
      console.log('set data for '+url);
      $(self).attr( 'href', url );
    }else
    {
      console.log('NOT set data for '+url);
    }
           }
        }  
    );
```

The reason is $.get is an asynchronous call. Meaning, all code after $.get will be executed even if the response from $.get has not been received yet.

Comment: $(this).attr( 'href', url ); is not working but prints in  the console

Comment: Please see modified code.  $(this).attr( 'href', url ) is now $(self).attr( 'href', url )